# How to control the order of elements generation in xsl

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am quite new to XSLT. And hence I am facing some difficulties .I have to transform a fairly large XML into a new XML . However , the way I am heading , I am facing some difficulties :

The input XML could be like :

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <Name>A</Name>
    <Role>Manager</Role>
    <Salary>5000$</Salary>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <Name>A</Name>
    <Role>Director</Role>
    <Salary>8000$</Salary>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

and the output XML should be like :

```
 <Manager>
      <Employee_Name>A</Employee_Name>
 </Manager>
 <Count_Of_Employee>2</Count_Of_Employee>
 <Director>
      <Employee_Name>B</Employee_Name>
 </Director>
```

Now If , I will apply the template `<xsl:Employees/Employee>` ,then it will check for every employee and will create the Director tag just after Manager Tag .

Hence on running the validation against the XSD , it will fail, as it expect to have a coutn tag in between .

So my first question is: how can I control the order of the output element nodes while writing up a generic template ?

My other question is: I have to transform a large XML, so I don't want to write `<xsl:element>` each time i am generating a tag ..

I tried to search various generic templates .. but couldn't find or write a good generic template for generating an element for which the tag name (in the target xml) are not the same as the one( in source XML) [ I found various generic templates for which element name is same in both the XMLs].

Can someone please help me on that .. 
I have looked in the XSL standard libraray as well .. but could not find a good alternative ..

Any suggestion or soultion would be a great help to me.

Comment: You show some sample input and the desired output; that's good.  But you need also to show us enough of the XSLT you are using to allow readers of the question to understand what you are doing (and then, if they can, diagnose what it is that is wrong in what you are doing).

Answer (score 0):

Reference implementation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <!--Suppress unmatched text-->
    <xsl:template match="text()" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <Manager>
                <Employee_Name>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Employees/Employee[Role/. = 'Manager']"/>
                </Employee_Name>
        </Manager>
        <Count_Of_Employee>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(Employees/Employee)"/>
        </Count_Of_Employee>
        <Director>
                <Employee_Name>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Employees/Employee[Role/. = 'Director']"/>
                </Employee_Name>
        </Director>
    </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Employee">
        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```